# Granted key is not visible in CanonicalGrantee - Amazon s3 ACL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have a special use-case where I manage a aws account with one bucket and i have customers to whom i should give access.

I found s3 ACL policy suits my requirement [Editing bucket policy seems like not a good idea since it has 20kb limit]

So I have come up with this idea:
1) Create a bucket xyz
2) create a folder(object) for each customer.
3) grant full writes to that customer to his folder(object) - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-using-java-sdk.html

This is where I'm stuck. Say currently I have two aws accounts (Admin,customer1). With admin aws account, I have created a bucket(xyz) and a folder(cust1) and granted read access to customer1 aws account. But when i logged in with customer1 aws account and went to console.aws.amazon.com/s3, I didn't find this folder and bucket({xyz}/cust1). Kindly help me out. Below is the snippet code I have used.

Apologies for my grammar!

```
//Here getBucket() gives "xyz" and getpath() returns "cust1/"
ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
metadata.setContentLength(0);
InputStream emptyContent = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(getBucket(),getPath(), emptyContent, metadata);
// send request to S3 to create folder
connection.putObject(putObjectRequest);


AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
acl=connection.getObjectAcl(getBucket(),getPath());
//System.out.println(acl);
acl.grantPermission(new CanonicalGrantee("asdkjaskdjalskdjalkdjEXAMPLE"), Permission.ReadAcp);
```